# Can someone please prove this limit via the squeeze theorem

Tags: limits

Can someone please prove that this limit exists using squeeze theorem?
$$\lim_{x,y\to 0,0}\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}.$$

Another question I've to ask is for $$y = x^2$$ can we not prove that the limit does not exist? If the case is true then the limit becomes: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{5x^4}{x^2+8x^4}.$$.
Can't that limit be solved using L'Hospital's rule and get a value that is not 0?
(Just for reference when we approach from both the axis, the limit is 0).

I'm sorry if my framing of the question is messy but

TLDR: I saw this question somewhere which shows that a limit exists but when I tried to use different methods of approaching the limit it gave me different answers.

Comment: For $x\ne 0$, $$\frac{5x^4}{x^2+8x^4}=\frac{5}{1+8x^2}$$ which tends to zero with $x$.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is not the alpha and omega of limits computation, and anyway it is valid for function of a single variable.

Comment: "TLDR" ? If you write that out, I upvote the question.

Comment: @AnginaSeng "$x^2$" is missing in the numerator

Comment: @Peter too late to edit now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$

$$0 \le \left\vert \frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}\right\vert \le \left\vert\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2}  \right\vert\le \frac{5}{2} \vert x \vert \left\vert\frac{\vert x y \vert}{x^2+y^2}  \right\vert \le \frac{5\vert x \vert }{2}$$

as $\vert x y \vert \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R$.

As $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \vert x \vert = 0$, you get the desired conclusion by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Minor error: there is an $8$ in the denominator.

Comment: This is not an error. I used  $\frac{1}{x^2 + 8y^2} \le \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$

Comment: Right, I didn't look carefully.

Comment: I also wanted to ask what exactly was wrong with the method I used, ie using y = x^2

Comment: The limit exists on the curve $y=x^2$. It is zero. This is coherent with the fact that the limit exists at $(0,0)$.

Comment: So what exactly from my explaination in my question was wrong? Was it the fact that you couldn't apply L'Hopital's rule? Or something else?

Comment: It is the fact that the limit do exists.

Comment: Yet with my method I'm getting a different limit. I do realize the limit exists as shown by not only by your awesome but several others too. So yes I realize the limit exists. However, I wanted to ask what exactly was wrong with how I calculated the limit at y = x^2.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}\right|=5|y|\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+8y^2}\right|\le 5|y|\to0.$$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: right. Nor did I specialize the case $x=0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: on second reading, I humbly prefer my solution, as it takes less tricks.

Comment: I'm fine if your prefer your solution!

Comment: Why dividing by $x^2$? it seems not necessary to obtain a clear result.

Comment: @user: you are right, but leaving no trace of $x$ in the numerator makes it more striking. I will update.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\left|\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}\right|=\frac{5x^2|y|}{x^2+8y^2}\le \frac{5x^2|y|+5|y|y^2}{x^2+y^2}= 5|y|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=5|y| \to 0$$

or also more simply

$$\left|\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}\right|
=5|y|\frac{x^2}{x^2+8y^2}
\le5|y| \to 0$$

Comment: Yes there are many ways indeed! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

0)$(x,y)\not =(0,0)$;

1)$x=0;$ $y\not=0;$ The limit $=0$;

2)$y=0$; $x\not=0$; The limit $=0$;

3)$x,y \not =0$;

Then

$|\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}| \lt \frac{5x^2|y|}{x^2} =5|y| \rightarrow 0.$

Comment: Nice solution Peter! Bye

Comment: user. Thanks, bye.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use polar coordinates:
$$\lim_{x,y\to 0,0}\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+8y^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta\cdot r\sin\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+8r^2\sin^2\theta},$$
and observe that $\;|\cos^2\theta\sin\theta|\le 1$, whereas $\:\cos^2\theta+8\sin^2\theta=1+7\sin^2\theta\ge 1$.